# Creating a authentification key generator in Lua

Tags: lua

I have created a script for a video game, i want to avoid people pirating it.

I will distribute the script as byte code.

People who buy the script will get a key, they will enter the key into the script and it will work for a month (keys use clock time to know when expired) after a month they get another key from me. (expires every month to avoid uploads to pirate sites, If i see it on a pirate site i can contact owner of that key)

So, The question.
I want to create a CD key generator/algorithm. What would be the best way of doing this or are there generators out there in lua that do this better?

Edit: I used the CD-Key generator "CD Key Generator v7.1" to generate keys, and put all keys inside the encrypted script.

Comment: Regardless of what you do, you can't prevent pirating. Except requiring access to online servers to play the game (e.g. a MMO). I suggest making it as friendly as possible to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response, My goal is to at least require piraters to change something on their computer. Like changing computer date etc. Otherwise it as simple as putting the script in a folder and clicking run.

Comment: For a 'CD key', you don't even need to do that; just give people a key.

Answer (score 3):

Like most DRM schemes, the only people inconvenienced by your DRM will be paying customers. People using the pirated version will never even know it was there.

Bytecode can be decompiled. If you encrypt it, the cracker needs to buy 1 pin and grab the decrypted code from memory. If you put in a pin check, he'll just remove the check. So on and so forth. There's no way you can protect your code that someone can't simply *remove*, so pirates will have a better user experience than legitimate users.